# error C2143: syntax error: missing ',' before 'const'

Tags: c++, visual-studio

```
template <class E, class K>
class SortedChain {
public:
    SortedChain() { first = 0; }
    ~SortedChain();
    bool IsEmpty() { return (first == 0); }
    //int Length() const;
    //bool Search (const K& k, const E& e);
    SortedChain<E, K>& Delete(const K& k, E& e);
    SortedChain<E, K>& Insert(const K& k, const E& e);
    ***SortedChain<E, K>& Merge(SortedChain<E, K> & S2 const);***
    void Output() const;
private:
    Node<E, K> *first;
};
```

sortedchain merge is giving me the following errors:

- error C2143: syntax error: missing ',' before 'const'
- note: see reference to class template instantiation 'SortedChain' being compiled
- error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int

any help is appreciated

Comment: `const SortedChain<E, K> & S2`

Comment: Simple typographical error. Shut her right down.

Comment: What is `SortedChain<E, K> & S2 const` supposed to mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have only error in placement of `const`
If you want to make argument reference constant then use below

```
template <class E, class K>
class SortedChain {
public:
    SortedChain() { first = 0; }
    ~SortedChain();
    bool IsEmpty() { return (first == 0); }
    //int Length() const;
    //bool Search (const K& k, const E& e);
    SortedChain<E, K>& Delete(const K& k, E& e);
    SortedChain<E, K>& Insert(const K& k, const E& e);
    SortedChain<E, K>& Merge(const SortedChain<E, K> & S2);// change this
    void Output() const;
private:
    Node<E, K> *first;
};
```

And you can to make that function constant for class object then use this

```
template <class E, class K>
class SortedChain {
public:
    SortedChain() { first = 0; }
    ~SortedChain();
    bool IsEmpty() { return (first == 0); }
    //int Length() const;
    //bool Search (const K& k, const E& e);
    SortedChain<E, K>& Delete(const K& k, E& e);
    SortedChain<E, K>& Insert(const K& k, const E& e);
    SortedChain<E, K>& Merge(SortedChain<E, K> & S2) const;// change this
    void Output() const;
private:
    Node<E, K> *first;
};
```

Comment: thanks to you and iBug for answering that